# Add the play script to your PATH in Mac

Tags: java, macos, path, playframework, installation

I'm not good with the terminal, so I have no idea what this means....

you should add the framework installation directory to your system PATH. On UNIX systems, this means doing something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/play20
```

On Windows you’ll need to set it in the global environment variables. This means update the PATH in the environment variables and don’t use a path with spaces.

If you're on UNIX, make sure that the play script is executable (otherwise do a chmod a+x play).

Can someone guide me through these steps. I have the Play 2.0 Folder placed in my /Documents.

[image]

Comment: Refering to your screenshot. Does ~/Documents/play-2.0.3 folder exist? And is there a play binary file within it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I did:

Download the play framework, extracted it to my desktop, open up iterm and `vi ~/.bash_profile`
add path: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/*your-username*/Desktop/play-2.2.0` save the file (that's press esc and type :wq [save and quit]) reload your bash_profile, just type `source ~/.bash_profile` cd to your directory and `type play` and your done.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest installing Play with [Brew](https://brew.sh/) if using OS X on Mac.

First install Brew

`ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)`

Then install Play

`brew install play`

Open .bash_profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Ensure that /usr/local/bin is in your path by updating or adding the PATH line to something like this  :

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal window, and Play should be on your path.

You may also want to install (via brew) Scala, SBT etc.

Answer (score 1):

In `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/play20`, `/path/to/play20` is a placeholder for your real path, which should be `/Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play20` [drag the folder from Finder into Terminal window for the actual name] - so type:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play20
```

This tells your shell to look into such folder for executables. Then:

```
chmod +x /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play20/play
```

This gives `play` file execution permission. Now close and reopen Terminal, and type `play` followed by enter.

Comment: @RonyJohn did you physically drag your folder into Terminal to get the actual path? If so, type `cd thePathThatWasMagicallyPasted` and see if you have a `play` file there.

Comment: Yes, I do see play-2.0.3. I did 'cd Documents' and did 'ls'.

Comment: Then just replace `play20` with `play-2.0.3` in answer's text.

Comment: I think I did it like the way you told me? But, I dont see it responding. Image Attached!

Comment: Should I be in the documents directory or outside when I run the commands?

Comment: @RonyJohn : if you give **absolute** path `/Users/rony/Documents...` you can do it from anywhere, otherwise you can go to the folder `cd ~/Documents/` first and do the same with relative path: `chmod +x play-2.0.3/play`, the tilda symbol points to your home directory, so `cd ~/Documents/` is equivalent of `cd /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/`, while writing the path use TAB key, it will show you available files/folders in current possition

Answer (score 1):

You can also use symlink(s) in `/usr/bin` to point exact file, this is usefull, when you're using more than one version of play on the system

*BTW (I can see that you performed reverse operation in your previous question :) -removed the previous: /usr/bin/play command )*

(paste each line separately and confirm):

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/bin
chmod +x /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-2.0.3/play
ln -ls /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-2.0.3/play play
exit
```

Other sample - `git master` in this case

```
# this creates new folder in your docs, 
# and clones current master version of Play from GitHub to 
# /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-from-github/Play20 folder

cd ~/Documents
mkdir play-from-github
cd play-from-github/
git clone https://github.com/playframework/Play20.git

# this sets alternative command as in sample 1
sudo -i
cd /usr/bin
chmod +x /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-from-github/Play20/play
ln -ls /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-from-github/Play20/play play-master
exit
```

Finally now you can check which command points to which version:

```
ls -la /user/bin | grep play
```

should give something like:

```
... play -> /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-2.0.3/play
... play-master -> /Users/ronyjohn007/Documents/play-from-github/Play20/play
```

after terminal reopen they both should be available as common commands.

**Note:** of course you can't use `play` command with applications created with `play-master new ...` and vice-versa!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your ~/.profile file and add:

export PLAY_HOME=your-play-directory
export PATH=$PATH:$PLAY_HOME